# how remove index.php to access controller in laravel

Tags: laravel, url, indexing, controller, http-status-code-404

I can't remove index.php in url when  i open the controller.

sitename/  works.

sitename/index.php  wors.

sitename/about  not working.

sitename/index.php/about works

---

.httaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>

    Options -MultiViews

</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

---

Apache2 virtual host:

```
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    Alias /comunion /var/www/html/boletinesUC/public

    <Directory /var/www/html>

        AllowOverride All

   </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Why?
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your site is residing in a sub-folder inside html folder. You should change your `DocumentRoot` to point to the public folder of Laravel project.

Change your Apache2 Virtual Host to the following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project_name/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Also make sure your Apache2 configuration in `apache2.conf` has the following configuration

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Finally, don't forget to restart your web server

```
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I made the changes and rebooted the server. But the same thing is still happening. =/

Comment: is apache rewrite module on?

Answer (score 0):

Create a .htaccess file in your Laravel root directory if it does not exists already

Add below code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now you should be able to access the website without the "/public/index.php/" part.